# image in slider don't work proerly

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have a slider in:
[my page](http://petrotat.com/test1/index.php/fa/%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA/44-rerer)
image in this slider are hidden but they are exist.
but when i go to inspect element and select any image tag in this slider and then right click and "scroll into view" slider shows these image.
I need a solution for show these image properly.
I use joomla and helix3 framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS or header:

```
.bxslider12{
    float: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Dont know if its showing correct images , thats for you to figure out. But its showing your slideshow.